# Difference between MouseDoubleClick and TouchDoubleClick

Tags: c#, showdialog

I have the following issue:

I have a MainWindow in which I call via `MouseDoubleClick` Event->

```
CustomView view= new CustomView();
view.ShowDialog();
```

Still works with MOUSE and TOUCH `Doubleclick`. But If i open the view with `TouchDoubleClick` I have to click twice on a button inside the `CustomView`?(Window isn't focused, I have already tried `Keyboard.Focus(this)`, `this.Focus` in the loaded Event in `CustomView`).

[Example](https://support.plassertheurer.com/ws/?9112a9e0-cf68-4313-b071-ff564486ee82)